Type or Namespace of an Existing Script Could Not be Found
On a gameobject, I have a script that wants to access another script on another gameobject.
   public PlayerController playerCont;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        canSwing = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canSwing && !playerCont._grounded)
        {
            anim2.Play();
            StartCoroutine(Swing());
        }

But I get the error:  The type or namespace name 'PlayerController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Although, the other script DOES exist!

Can anyone help me? I've tried a lot of things.
Thanks :)!
(I have tried referencing a GameObject instead, and getting the script off of that, and yes, the bool I'm trying to access is public, and so is the script class)
EDIT: someone asked for the assembly info

that's for the PlayerController

that's for the SwingScript
hope that helps!

(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

@shingo I do not think so, but could you explain this a bit more? I'm not really solid on what a directive or assembly reference is

Are there any other errors? Before that error?  Its asking if you need to use a using statement to make that class visible.

@BugFinder nope, no other errors. And the classes I am using in both scripts are exactly the same.

perhaps paste both classes?

@BugFinder nope, unfortunately did nothing :(

wtf? no, I said paste both classes, eg SHOW us both full classes, you havent so.. i dont know what you did, but that wasnt it it..

public class SwingScript : MonoBehaviour
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour, IPlayerController
these are the classes that both scripts are using, is this what you meant? Sorry for the confusion.

No. I said FULL classes. Im just gonna leave you to it

To expand on what others have mentioned, a using directive or assembly reference is a way to access code found in another library. The error indicates it cannot load PlayController because it does know where that class is defined. This typically means you have to add a statement to the top of the file in which you're trying to use that class, to tell the code where it can load the class from. For example, you've probably seen using System.Collections; or using System; in your scripts before, yes? That's likely what you need. Is PlayerController a class you defined or is it a class from Unity?

unfortunately you have cut off the Assembly Information bit in your screenshot ... can you include that?

for the SwingScript, the assemblies I used are            using System; using UnityEngine; using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic;                    and for the PlayerController, I used      using System; using UnityEngine; using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic;                  Is this what you are asking for? Sorry if I am confused.

@derHugo I have edited the post to include screenshots of both!

Your new script where you are getting these errors from - is it placed under a different assembly? For instance using an Assembly Definition

@derHugo, I do not think so, no. They both say they are under the Assembly CSharp.dll

ah yeah true .. weird indeed. I would try and comment out the entire content of your class (not the class itself in case it is used somewhere) - but anything referencing that player controller and let Unity do a fresh compile - then try to add it again. Sometimes compilation order can indeed mess up things
